Numeric cell values get appended with extra decimal digits and numeric date value
I am using below code to extract data from Excel and generate the .PX file by using Excel Interop C# library. Also when I am trying to read the decimal numbers from the Excel, I am getting additional fraction numbers in the output data. For example, the value 1127.17 is reading as "1127.17000001013". This date value is coming from different cells and different worksheets. I don't have option to fix the cell number to apply the date format. Is there a way to interpret the date in correct format like "MM/dd/yyyy" format and read the decimal numbers with displayed fraction numbers as it is by using Excel Interop C# library?
object[,] data = worksheet.get_Range("F3:IK3").Cells.Value2;
for (int j = 1; j <= data.Length; j++)
{
   string strTagValue = string.Empty;
   if (data[1, j] is double oaDate)
   {
      DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(oaDate); <-- Here not only date as well as dollar amount also converted into date value
      strTagValue = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
   else
   {
      strTagValue = Convert.ToString(data[1, j]);
   }
}



Formula applied in the above cell:

Numeric Data issue:


Updated:
Excel.Range range = ws1065.get_Range($"F{i}:IK{i}");
object[,] data = new object[range.Rows.Count, range.Columns.Count];
for (int k = 1; k <= range.Rows.Count; k++)
{
  for (int l = 1; l <= range.Columns.Count; l++)
  {
    if (range.Cells[k, l].Value != null)
    {
      string strDataType = range.Cells[k, l].Value.GetType().Name;
      double dlTagValue;
      bool isDouble = double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(range.Cells[k, l].Value), out dlTagValue);
      if (strDataType.ToUpper() == "STRING" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(range.Cells[k, l].Value) &&
          isDouble && DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(DateTime.FromOADate(range.Cells[k, l].Value)),                                                                     formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,                                                                  out startDate))
      {
         isDate = true;
      }
      else
      {
         isDate = false;
       }
    }
    if (isDate)
    {
       DateTime dtTagValue = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(range.Cells[k, l].Value));
       data[k - 1, l - 1] = dtTagValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    else
    {
      decimal dTagValue;
      bool isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(Convert.ToString(range.Cells[k, l].Value), out dTagValue);
      if (isDecimal)
      {
        bool isLong = dTagValue == (long)dTagValue;
        if (isLong)
        {
          data[k - 1, l - 1] = range.Cells[k, l].Value;
        }
        else
        {
          data[k - 1, l - 1] = string.Format("{0:F2}", dTagValue);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        data[k - 1, l - 1] = range.Cells[k, l].Value;
      }
    }
  }
}

Zip Code:


FYI range.Cells[k, l].Text will give you the string seen by a user (though with a length limit for very long text).

In Excel, the date and time is represented by a double-precision floating-point number. To convert these numbers to DateTime, use DateTime.FromOADate(Double) Method:
DateTime adate = DateTime.FromOADate(worksheet.get_Range("F3").Cells.Value2);

Consider Remarks in "Range.Value2 property".
Excel displays the floating-point numbers in a form convenient to read. But the numbers can contain small decimal parts like 0.00000001013 which appears due to various conversion and mathematic operations. You need to round numbers as required:
double anum = Math.Round(worksheet.get_Range("J5").Cells.Value2, 2);

// 1127.17000001013 --> 1127.17

You can also address ranges by these ways:
worksheet.Range["F4:H5"].Value;
worksheet.Range["F4"].Value;
int row = 4;
string address = "F" + row;
worksheet.Range[address].Value;
DateTime adate = DateTime.FromOADate(worksheet.get_Range(address).Cells.Value2);
int col = 6
worksheet.Cells[row, col];

More information:

Console.WriteLine("\r\nAddress: {0}", address);
Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", oSheet.Range[address].Value.GetType().Name);
Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", oSheet.Range[address].Value);
Console.WriteLine("Text: {0}", oSheet.Range[address].Text);
Console.WriteLine("Number Format: {0}", oSheet.Range[address].NumberFormat);
var hasformula = (bool)oSheet.Range[address].HasFormula;
if (hasformula) Console.WriteLine("Formula: {0}", oSheet.Range[address].Formula);


Address: H8
Type: DateTime
Value: 10.11.2024 0:00:00
Text: 10.11.2024
Number Format: m/d/yyyy
Address: H9
Type: Double
Value: 1127,17000001013
Text: 1127,17
Number Format: General
Address: I8
Type: Double
Value: 12
Text: $12,00
Number Format: [$$-409]#,##0.00
Address: I9
Type: Double
Value: 3
Text: 3
Number Format: General
Formula: =H6+I6

UPD
Be aware date values can be stored as text:


The date values are not coming from fixed cells. So I can't go for fixed cell based approach.

Zip Code and Date values are stored as "Double" data type in the cells. If I check the data type with Double data type, both of the values are satisfying the condition and converted into date format.

Read Remarks in Range.Value2 property

I have updated my final solution in the question.

Glad to help you. But I guess it would be better to detect the type of cell's content by .Value.GetType().Name not by NumberFormat which can be changed without notice. It should be four values only for .Value.GetType().Name: DateTime, Double, String, and Boolean.

range.Cells[k, l].Value.GetType().Name is returning "String" for the cell which is containing Date value (Number Format).

??? Look at my answer please: "Address: H8 Type: DateTime". "String" is returned if the cell contains a text. If the date stored as a text, the "String" type is returned. In Excel, you can check the content type of a cell (e. g. 'E4') by the formula in another cell: =ISTEXT(E4). The problem in that a cell can contain a text and has the number format for a date. In this case the format doesn't affect the representation (you can check it in Excel). And, you  are not able to determine value type by NumberFormat. It seems the worksheet contains inconsistent data.

So, if the worksheet contains dates stored as a text, the best way I can suggest is to check if (.Value.GetType().Name == "String") and use TryParse or TryParseExcat methods of DateTime.

I have to convert the date value by using "DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble("42047")" because date value is stored as number and pass this value to TryParseExact method. Zip Code also stored string and converted into wrong format like "12/26/2151" and TryParseExact condition succeeded.

I have updated the latest code in the question.

Please clarify what do you need. Are you still not able to perform everything what you need?

My excel is containing inconsistent data. Date is stored in excel as number not in Date time format. Zip code is also stored as number. I have to use FromOADate before checking TryParseExact method. In this case Zip code is also converted into date by using FromOADate

Ok, the only a case which can help you is that the ZIP code converted to Date is out of acceptable date limits. You can check it for a decision. Otherwise, you should have additional information to differentiate ZIP codes and everything else you need.
